# Column count doesn't match value count but i think it does?

Tags: php, sql

I have a database with 5 Column: join_date, week, done, should and comment.

I have a insert.php file:

```
<body>
<div id="insert">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
$dbhost = 'host';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'pass';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
{
   $join_date = addslashes ($_POST['join_date']); 
   $week = addslashes ($_POST['week']);
   $done = addslashes ($_POST['done']);
   $should = addslashes ($_POST['should']);
   $comment = addslashes ($_POST['comment']);

}
else
{
   $join_date = addslashes ($_POST['join_date']);
   $week = addslashes ($_POST['week']);
   $done = addslashes ($_POST['done']);
   $should = addslashes ($_POST['should']);
   $comment = addslashes ($_POST['comment']);
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO statistika2014 ".
       "(join_date, week, done, should, comment ) ".
       "VALUES('$join_date','$week','$done','$should', '$comment', NOW())";
mysql_select_db('table');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td><input name="join_date" type="date" id="join_date" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="week" type="number" id="week" placeholder="week"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="done" type="number" id="emp_done" placeholder="done"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="should" type="number" id="should" placeholder="should"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="comment" type="text" id="comment" placeholder="comment"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Submit">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</div>  
</body>
```

When I usme this insert.php file I get the message: 
"Could not enter data: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"
but I do not get it!! I have 5 column and 5 values or am I wrong counting?

I'm using a free host. Is it possible that they need something to refresh?

Please help

Comment: **SIX** !!!!!!!!!!!! values. sorry seems real clear ro me

Comment: sorry forgot to close vote earlier :-)

Comment: Ah, the missing link you are Dagon.

Comment: wont he be embarrassed if he ever bothers to come back to the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add another field for date or whatever the field is called in the database.

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO statistika2014 ".
    "(join_date, week, done, should, comment, date ) ".
    "VALUES('$join_date','$week','$done','$should', '$comment', NOW())";
```

Answer (score 2):

Learn to count?

```
  "(join_date, week, done, should, comment ) ".
      1         2       3   4        5
   "VALUES('$join_date','$week','$done','$should', '$comment', NOW())";
               1           2       3        4          5         6???
```

Since when does `5 == 6`?

Comment: That graphical representation deserves a +1 just on its own ;-)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sEUdmtyJ3U

Comment: @Dagon, that's a nice video .. LOL

Answer (score 0):

You are entering Now() as a sixth value

Answer (score 0):

Your values clause has one extra field NOW() which makes 6 values against 5 fields.

```
       "(join_date, week, done, should, comment ) ".
   "VALUES('$join_date','$week','$done','$should', '$comment', NOW())";
```

Answer (score 0):

You either want this...

```
//assuming your time column is named timestamp

$sql = "INSERT INTO statistika2014 ".
   "(join_date, week, done, should, comment, timestamp ) ".
   "VALUES('$join_date','$week','$done','$should', '$comment', NOW())";
```

Or this...

```
// Just set your 6th column to TIMESTAMP in your DB and it will auto update on a new insert
$sql = "INSERT INTO statistika2014 ".
   "(join_date, week, done, should, comment ) ".
   "VALUES('$join_date','$week','$done','$should', '$comment')";
```

But you're clearly trying to insert 6 values into 5 columns.
Either add the 6th column in the SQL call.
Or set it to auto update the timestamp to NOW in the DB, and remove it from your call